# Practical Sizing Of Push Pull vs Active Clamp forward

Tags: power, transformer, dc-dc-converter, magnetics, push-pull

I am looking to get some practical feedback regarding push pull design.

I am wanting to design an isolated DC to DC converter with the following requirements:

- Vin: 18-36V
- Vout: 5 V
- Iout: 6 A
- f_switching: 500kHz -> f_clock= 1Mhz (*Must remained Synced*)

I am wanting to make this design reasonably compact, because I will also want to meet MIL-STD-461 (usually big).

That being said, from the literature out there the push pull seems to be the  more compact option, yes this would be my first push pull design.

**Pros:**
 - quadrant 1 and 3 utilization for the BH curve
 - smaller input/output ripple current (usually easier to filter)
 - both FETS referenced to ground (Low loss NFETS)

**Cons:**
 - double the core losses ( from going -B to + B)
 - More Complex Transformer
 - Not as much support for Push pull applications,Most textbooks/reference material does not call out the push pull for less than 50W applications

As stated in [Pressman's section 7.3.2.2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071482725) I could double the switching frequency, however, I am concerned about the 3x transformer losses as well as the increased EMI Emissions.

Note: For the push pull controller I am liking either  the [LM25037](http://www.ti.com/product/LM25037) or the [LTC3723](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3723.html); Either one of these converters may be used in current mode to combat flux imbalancing.

**My question to the forum** is whether of not going to a push pull over an active clamp forward is a good idea for a 30W application, with my considerations of space, EMI, and efficiency.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Just one thought to add to your mix. Any possibility of "dithering" your operating frequency in order to spread out the EMI to meet requirements? (Could be as simple as ramping back and forth between two frequencies at some chosen rate.)

Comment: thank you for AN EXCELLENT SUGGESTION Jonk....but sadly cannot, i must remain in a derived clock setup thus I must remained synced. I have edited the requirements above.

Comment: Please draw the circuit as opposed to trying to describe it. At 30 watts, it seems to be on the right street for a flyback converter.

Comment: If you want to push \$F_{sw}\$ at 500 kHz or so, zero-voltage switching (ZVS) or near-ZVS is a must. As pointed out by Andy, a QR flyback converter could do the job provided you reflect enough voltage to the primary side at turn off. A push-pull is a bit of an overkill for a 30-W project. Besides, there is no ZVS. The active-clamp forward (ACF) is an option but usually sized for slightly higher power. It can be a little tricky to stabilize though. The active-clamp flyback with true ZVS could indeed be a valid option and you have good controllers these days.

Comment: Verbal / Andy, My main concern with the Flyback of course is EMI. While I am aware that I can of course get a magnetic with shielding, I am a tad worried that my EMI  filter would eat up space quickly. This again could be further reduced by potentially using valley mode switching, but I do not have much experience with this technique.

Comment: Lastly, (please correct me if I am wrong here) I do not believe that a ZVS system may be considered truly synchronous, "as the  positive side effect of quasi-resonant switching is that because switching is triggered when a valley is detected, rather than at a fixed frequency, a degree of frequency jitter is introduced, spreading the RF emission spectrum" - ------source:https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2014/aug/a-review-of-zero-voltage-switching-and-its-importance-to-voltage-regulation